# How to use c++ code on android using unity?

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, static-libraries

I try to create an android AR application. I use unity ide.

I create .so file from cpp file using ndk-build on ubuntu. Content of the file :

```
#include ...

extern "C" {    
    int returnInt()
    {    
        int returnVal = 4;
        return returnVal;
    }    
}
```

My .so file is created for many processor types. I copy it and paste under assets/plugin/android/armeabi-v7a. On unity, I load this .so file on `Start` function by 
    `[DllImport ("aruco-build")]
    public static extern int returnInt();`.

I call this function on unity :

`guiText.text = returnInt.toString()`

I create apk from unity and run this apk on android phone. I can't see `returnInt` value on screen. I don't understand reason of it.

Comment: My experience was that you need to wrap the C call with Java, and call the Java from Unity.

Comment: No, I created and used similar c++ code on android using unity. It works.

Comment: IIRC, .so files are usually under a /libs folder? i.e. assets/plugin/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/your_so_file? Never worked with Android NDK plugins, so this is sort of a shot in the dark

Comment: I put .so file under assets/plugin/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a. But it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Check the ADB logs when you run the APK.  (2) Also, did you spell the project name correctly? (3) Is your Text actually visible on the screen? (try putting a dummy value, and see if its actually visible.) Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

returnInt is a function and you should treat it like a function
`returnInt().toString();`
and you should put your .so file in Plugins/Android
I hope it work